# How to pass item ID to ViewModel?

Tags: android, data-binding, android-mvvm

I have little problem with pass Recyclerview item ID from Activity to ViewModel. I need this ID to edit objects.
Does anyone know how to do it in accordance with the MVVM architecture?

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: Nothing because I don't know how to do it. Paramteres from editexts are not problem, but I no have idea how to get ID of same item.